# Can't SSH into Vagrant VM (without using vagrant ssh) part 2

Tags: linux, ssh, vagrant

This is a follow-up question to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33621210/2909897). I've used the same Vagrantfile, but have commented out two lines I don't think are necessary.

I'm trying to ssh into my Vagrant box without using `vagrant ssh`. Below is my Vagrantfile and ssh configuration information:

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 6144
    v.cpus = 2
    v.name = "mb_vagrant"
  end

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  # config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  # config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8001, guest: 8001

end
```

The output from `vagrant ssh-config`:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "/Users/mbigras/Google Drive/tmp/chef-repo/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```

I've tried `ssh`ing into my machine with the following command:

```
$ ssh -i "/Users/mbigras/Google Drive/tmp/chef-repo/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key" -p 2222 vagrant@192.168.33.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.33.10 port 2222: Connection refused
```

Also, as per the solution described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621585/2909897), I've tried removing `~/.ssh/known_hosts` before attempting to connect; however, it also doesn't work:

```
$ rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ ssh -i "/Users/mbigras/Google Drive/tmp/chef-repo/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key" -p 2222 vagrant@192.168.33.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.33.10 port 2222: Connection refused
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you're wanting to use 16.04 I can recommend [bento/ubuntu-16.04](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04) because they use the standard username: vagrant, password: vagrant convention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ssh service is bound to host machine's (i.e: **127.0.0.1**) port **2222**, but in the VM (guest machine) is still listening on port 22 (as the default port).
So, you should connect to port **22** on **192.168.33.10** or **2222** on **127.0.0.1**. I.e:

```
$ ssh -i "<vagranfile-path>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key" \
-p 22 vagrant@192.168.33.10
```

or

```
$ ssh -i "<vagranfile-path>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key" \
-p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

Also, it is not required to remove `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Adding the following option will avoid host fingerprint check: `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`

Comment: What's the difference between guest machine and VM? I thought they are the same. Do you have any book recommendation to understand what you have written here (port binding, guest/host machine and their connectivity/networking, etc)

Comment: You are right. Guest machine and VM are the same. Actually it was a mistake on the answer wording. Just fixed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set the port forwarding section of vagrantfile like so:

```
  # using a specific IP.
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2290
```

this will allow "normal" ssh into the the guest without go through vagrant ssh

Answer (score 0):

by the way if anyone is stuck in a wsl prompt and testing other than using the vagrant-ssh command then you can simply use what the ip address of eth0 is bound to, you can find this out using `ip route` you can then plug in the ip there to your ssh command and you should have no issues so my output from ip route is:

```
default via 172.19.192.1 dev eth0 proto kernel
172.19.192.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.197.225
```

so just use `172.19.192.1` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Soo

`ssh vagrant@172.19.192.1 -p 2222 -i ".\vagrant\<path>"`